# How to skip ignore error and test another condition python

Tags: python

I currently have the following code. I am trying to raise an error if in1 is not an integer.The problem that I am currently facing is that my program won't go past the raise ValueError line.

```
def test(in1):

  if not isinstance(in1, int):
    raise ValueError('error')
```

If anyone has any solutions to solve this problem I would really appreciate it, thanks

Comment: What arguments do you call `test` with? Also, _I am trying to raise an error if in2 is an integer_ but actually you raise an error if it is not an integer.

Comment: If the error gets raised, it's because the `in2` you passed to the function wasn't an `int`.

Comment: What if you try to log in2 type, by doing `print("in2 type is %s" % in2.__class__)` in the beginning of the function.

Comment: It is better to understand the reason of the error, not to suppress it. Please, show us how you call `test(...)` or do what @andnik suggested.

Comment: How are you calling your function? How are you assigning your inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Try casting in2 to an integer first:

```
def test(in1, in2, in3):

  if not isinstance(in2, int):
      try:
          in2=int(in2)
      except:
          raise ValueError('error')

  elif in2 == 1:
    in1 = in1[-len(in3):] + in1[:-len(in3)]
  print(in1)

test("supermarket","3","cash")
test("supermarket",3,"cash")
```

Output:

```
supermarket
supermarket
```